# Indent everything after h1, h2, etc. before the next, one, while stacking the indents, with CSS

Tags: html, css, markdown

I have a markdown file that I compile to an HTML file. However, when I do, it is unclear which paragraph belongs to which title. I would like to give the contents that come after a small nudge to the right, and have it move more to the right if there is a subheading after the first one.

```
# H1
## H2
text
## H2
```

```css
h1 ~ *, h2 ~ *, h3 ~ *, h4 ~ *, h5 ~ *, h6 ~ * {
    text-indent: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>H1</h1>
<h2>H2</h2>
<p>text</p>
<h2>H2</h2>
```

Expected output:

> ## H1
>
> ### H2
>
> text
>
> ### H2

Actual output:

> ## H1
>
> ### H2
>
> text
>
> ### H2

Comment: Doesn't the paragraph always follow its title? I don't understand the problem. At any rate, what have you tried? Please create a functioning snippet with your CSS.

Comment: Also, aren't you simply indenting _everything_ except the H1 headings? That's pretty trivial stuff. What's the problem?

Comment: @isherwood no, I am trying to indent the h2s after the h1s, the h3s after the h2s, etc

Comment: ```h1 ~ *:not(p) {text-indent: 16px;}```, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: You are going to have to specify the indent amounts for each one, they are not going to stack because the h1,h2,h3 etc does not have the elements as children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you really want is each progressively lower heading indented the same amount, and the paragraphs indented with respect to whatever heading they fall after. We'll use the [subsequent sibling combinator](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) (~) for that, as you did, which only selects siblings *after* the selector.

For standard readability all headings of the same level should be indented the same amount. Paragraphs are probably less important in that regard. I'm assuming that you'll adhere to proper document structure and not place an H3 immediately after an H1, for example.

Here I've defined a CSS variable using a [custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)* so that the indent factor can be updated at just one place and calculated for each rule.  I've opted to use  `rem` units for size consistent scaling across element types, but you could certainly use `em` units for variable indentation, or simply `px`.

```css
:root {
  --indent-unit: 1rem;
}

h2 {
  text-indent: calc(var(--indent-unit) * 1);
}

h2~p,
h3 {
  text-indent: calc(var(--indent-unit) * 2);
}

h3~p,
h4 {
  text-indent: calc(var(--indent-unit) * 3);
}

h4~p,
h5 {
  text-indent: calc(var(--indent-unit) * 4);
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading Level 1</h1>
<h2>Heading Level 2</h2>
<p>Paragraph.</p>
<p>Paragraph.</p>

<h3>Heading Level 3</h3>
<p>Paragraph.</p>
<p>Paragraph.</p>

<h2>Heading Level 2</h2>
<h3>Heading Level 3</h3>
<h4>Heading Level 4</h4>
<p>Paragraph.</p>
<p>Paragraph.</p>
```

<sub>*Internet Explorer [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), but [we don't care](https://css-tricks.com/a-business-case-for-dropping-internet-explorer/).</sub>